# Compiler warning while using @Value annotation in Kotlin project

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

Is there any type in Kotlin language that I could use in a late initialization instead of `java.lang.Integer` so that I do not get a compiler warning?

Let's say I have a class like this one:

```
class SomeClass {
 @Value(#{config['poolCapacity']?:'5000'})
 lateinit var somePool: Integer
}
```

I can't use `Int` type from Kotlin because it's primitive type and `lazeint` does not accept it.

If I stick to `java.lang.Integer` it works just fine but I am getting compiler warning of this sort:

> SomeClass.kt: (20, 24): This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use
>   kotlin.Int instead.

Obviously I might create needed type myself but I simply wonder if there is something out of the box and recommended that we should use in such situation and I simply can't find it? (Annotated constructor is not a solution in this particular case).

Comment: why not simply set it to -1, or Int.MinValue to mark it was not initialized?
Another option is to use BigInteger (but may have performance impact on scale)

Comment: @LiorBar-On I guess I was overthinking this one :) Simplicity is a king!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is don't to use a late-initialized property since Kotlin late-initialized property don't support for primitive types now, and you can initialize it with the default value of spring expression, for example:

```
@Value(#{config['poolCapacity']?:'5000'})
var somePool: Int = 5000
```

A complex example you can write a delegated properties, but you must annotated at `setter` by `@set` site-target rather than `field`/`property` , for example:

```
@set:Value(#{config['poolCapacity']?:'5000'})
var value by required<Int>()
```

---

```
inline fun <reified T> required(): ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {
    return object : ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {
        var value: T? = null;
        override fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T = value as T

        override fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I admit this would work, but I am not entirely sure if this is the only plausible solution.
If you do not mind I will give it a few more days. If no one suggests anything better I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's more like it in a bit more complex situation when you can't simply default it!

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz yes, sir. I'm glad it helped you. but I think you never need this complex features, since if the value is not found, spring will throw a bean can't initialized exception. just use the simplest solution is ok.